# can't properly implement a MODAL (beginner)

Tags: javascript, api, listview, crash, modal-dialog

Ive been stuck on this for a while now.

I have an API of a LIST that I want to display, each one of the objects on the list needs to be cliackable and a MODAL should appear with the LIST OBJECTS info ''pokemon height'', 'pokemon name'' and ''pokemon type''. The MODAL should also be CLOSED when clicking ESC or outside of the MODAL.

The thing is, I believe I added all the codes correctly but everytime I find an error, or the list simply disappears. I fix an error and another one appears, when there is no  errors it simply just doesn't work.  I am sorry if that is a rather simple thing to do but I am brand-new to programming and I am trying to learn.

It just seems that everytime I ''correct'' something, I get further away from the correct way of doing it. PLEASE if somebody could take a look in what I've done and give me some tips or point what should be done here.   THANKS

[HERE IS THE LINK TO MY "PROJECT":](https://github.com/mazaflame/simple-js-app1)

added functions to loadDetails, loadList, addListItem (it worked)

then by adding the MODAl, CLOSE MODAL, HIDE MODAL, it just doesnt answer accordingly

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I would recommend posting about a single, specific issue. In order to find a specific issue, build up your app one step at a time. When you encounter an error you cannot figure out, post only about that specific error, showing only the relevant code.